# SQL working with number in varchar column

Tags: sql, numbers, addition, varchar

I have this 11 digit long number that is stored in a `varchar` column, and I want to add another number to this number, a number that is composed of the second, third, fourth, fifth and sixth character followed by 5 zeros (e.g. 51030406787) the number I want to add is 1030400000. I want to do this in a query in SQL.

Comment: Some unusual form of encoding / encryption?

Comment: show a proper data sample

Comment: Did u tried and researched `left` function or `right`

Comment: Used Cast to obtain part of the number as a bigint, but my difficult is to add the five zeros after the number.

Comment: select cast( right(left ('5103040678',6),5)  as varchar(5))+'00000' will get your output, but please add requirement correctly

Comment: Example is 51030406787 + 1030400000 = 52060806787

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your string number column is named my_number  you could cast  the concatenated  string

```
      select my_number
          , cast(concat(substr(my_number,2,5), '00000')   AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
          , cast( my_number, AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) + 
                     cast(concat(substr(my_number,2,5), '00000')   AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
      from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard syntax would be something like:

```
select cast(col as bigint) + cast(substr(col, 2, 5) || '00000' as bigint)
```